# bxslider last slide wont be set as startSlide

Tags: jquery, carousel, bxslider

Im having issues setting the last slide in my bxslider as the first slide.

The following code sets all other slides to be first in the list, but the last slide always gets shown as the last in the list.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var count = $('.bxslider li.active').index();


  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 8,
    maxSlides: 8,
    slideWidth: 121,
    slideMargin: 12,
    pager: false,
    startSlide: count,
    moveSlides: 1,
    infiniteLoop: true
  });

});
```

Im not sure if this is to do with using infiniteLoop or something, but if anyone could shine some light on this that would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Could you create a fiddle using your code and demonstrating your issue?  http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/vgJ9X/18/ might be a good starting point because `bxslider` is already loaded.

Comment: Seems to be working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/4QWc9/

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same while trying to tweak some of the user experience.

I found that if slides are hidden before the slider is loaded, the 'startSlide' option will not be obeyed.

I had hidden all slides apart from the default slide via CSS, as the slides would initially show while loading then disappear once the bxSlider had initialised. To prevent this I created a css class called 'hideuntilloaded' which had an entry of `display:none;` and applied to the slides to prevent them displaying during loading. I then removed the class from the slides once the slider had successfully loaded.

This caused the above problem of the 'startSlide' option not being obeyed (as well as a few others including duplicate entries which started appearing!).

To get around this, make sure the slides are visible again before initialising the slider by removing the 'hiduntilloaded' class on the line before initiating the slider. eg: `$('.hideuntilloaded').removeClass('hideuntilloaded');`

It seems to still prevent the slides from flashing up during the load.

If you are doing anything similar with the visibility of the slides, then this could be the cause.